# MiniMax Algorithm for Tic Tac Toe failure

Tags: c++, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to implement a minimax algorithm for tic tac toe with alpha-beta pruning. Right now I have the program running, but it does not seem to be working. Whenever I run it it seems to input garbage in all the squares. I've implemented it so that my minimax function takes in a  board state and modifies that state so that when it is finished, the board state contains the next best move. Then, I set 'this' to equal the modified board. Here are my functions for the minimax algorithm:

```
void board::getBestMove() {
  board returnBoard;
  miniMax(INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX -1, returnBoard);

  *this = returnBoard;
}

int board::miniMax(int alpha, int beta, board childWithMaximum) {
  if (checkDone())
    return boardScore();

  vector<board> children = getChildren();
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    if(children.empty()) break;

    board curr = children.back();
    if (curr.firstMoveMade) { // not an empty board
      board dummyBoard;
      int score = curr.miniMax(alpha, beta, dummyBoard);

      if (computerTurn && (beta > score)) {
        beta = score;
        childWithMaximum = *this;
        if (alpha >= beta) break;
      } else if (alpha < score) {
        alpha = score;
        childWithMaximum = *this;
        if (alpha >= beta) break;
      }
    }
  }
  return computerTurn? alpha : beta;
}

vector<board> board::getChildren() {
  vector<board> children;

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
      if (getPosition(i, j) == '*') { //move not made here
        board moveMade(*this);
        moveMade.setPosition(i, j);
        children.push_back(moveMade);
      }
    }
  }

  return children;
}
```

And here are my full files if someone wants to try running it:

.cpp : http://pastebin.com/ydG7RFRX
.h   : http://pastebin.com/94mDdy7x

Comment: I've fixed the indentations on your code and massaged it into a more compact format. Please do this yourself prior to posting next time.

Comment: Presumably the board class's constructor will be of interest here. Please include it.

Comment: The class constructor is included in the paste bin. Thank you for your help! This is my first time asking a question.

Comment: you should try to eliminate all the irrelevant code from your question and include only the relevant pieces. This is important if you would like people to help you. We do not like digging through entire programs to try to solve problems.

Comment: The code that is inline with the post is all the code relevant to the miniMax algorithm. I didn't want to add much more because I felt that it would be too much code to dig through.

Comment: To extend what @Richard said, you should construct a [Minimal, Complete, Valid Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So you should eliminate all code irrelevant to the question from **your program** and then post your complete program in the question. This eliminates the possibility that you only post part of your program and the problem isn't actually there.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many issues with your code... you sure posted a lot of it. Because you are asking your question it is incumbent on you to try everything you can on your own first and then reduce your question to the smallest amount of code necessary to clarify what is going on. As it is, I don't feel that you've put much effort into asking this question.

But maybe I can still provide some help:

```
void board::getBestMove() {
  board returnBoard;
  miniMax(INT_MIN + 1, INT_MAX -1, returnBoard);

  *this = returnBoard;
}
```

See how you are saying `*this = returnBoard`.

That must mean that you want to get a board back from `miniMax`.

But look at how `miniMax` is defined!

```
int board::miniMax(int alpha, int beta, board childWithMaximum)
```

It accepts `childWithMaximum` via [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value) so it *cannot* return a board in this way.

what you wanted to say was probably:

```
int board::miniMax(int alpha, int beta, board & childWithMaximum)
```